# Como imprimir uma View em impressora padrao usando JavaScript ou c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, impressão

Preciso imprimir na impressora padrão o conteúdo de uma view. 
Como posso fazer isso usando c# ou javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é você chamar a função `print()` do  `JavaScript`. Ficaria assim o seu código:

**Este CSS serve apenas para não aparecer o botão de imprimir, ao clicar no mesmo**

```css
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

E em sua `View` você adiciona o botão para imprimir

```html
<div>
   <h3>Teste Impressão!</h3>
</div> 

<div class="no-print">
    <button type="button" value="imprimir" onclick="window.print();">Imprimir</button>
</div>
```

E em sua `View` você adiciona o botão para imprimir.

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIW3Nl).

Comment: Blz mais o conteudo a ser impresso vai ser o da minha view ?

Comment: @HansMiller o conteúdo será o que estiver na sua View.

Comment: @HansMiller Editei a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: tem como fazer para que o comando imprima diretamente ou seja automaticamente nao precisando confirmar a impressora?